# Most frequent integer in a list

Tags: python, beginner

Here was my attempt at finding the most frequent integers in a list, I feel like there are better ways to do this and I spent a great deal of time coming up with this solution, so please point me in the correct direction!

```
'''
Created on Jan 27, 2018
Problem statement: Find the most frequently occuring integer in a list and its occurence;
    input: 1 1 2 3 2 1 2
    output: [(1,3), (2, 3)]

@author: Anonymous3.1415
'''
from collections import Counter

def integer_frequency(int_list):
    int_freq = Counter()
    for i in int_list:
        int_freq[i] += 1
    cnt = 0
    values = sorted(int_freq.values())
    values.reverse()
    for x in values:
        if x == values[0]:
            cnt += 1
        else:
            break
    return int_freq.most_common(cnt)



int_list = list(map(int, raw_input().strip().split(' ')))
most_frequent = integer_frequency(int_list)
print(most_frequent)
```

Comment: watch out for an empty input list. There's currently no validation in place and it will raise a `ValueError` (unless the problem states your input will always be non-empty!)

Comment: Somewhat trivial, but since I think documentation is important: _occurrence, occurring_ take two 2 `r`s. As a matter of habit, spelling matters. I work in a trilingual office, and I can't tell you the number of times we've missed parts of a `length` refactoring because half of us write it phonetically (in our accent) as `lenght`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) to keep on taking tuples until they are not the same count anymore:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import takewhile

def integer_frequency(integers):
    int_freq = Counter(integers)
    most_common = int_freq.most_common(1)[0]
    return list(takewhile(lambda x: x[1] == most_common[1],
                          int_freq.most_common()))
```

I also renamed your `integer_list` to `integers`, because it can be any iterable of integers.

Alternatively, you could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the tuples by their frequency and return the group with the highest frequency, as @Gareth Reese has suggested [in the comments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/186162/most-frequent-integer-in-a-list/186258#comment355203_186258):

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import groupby

def integer_frequency(integers):
    return list(next(groupby(Counter(integers).most_common(),
                             key=lambda x: x[1]))[1])
```

This approach is consistently faster (by a small amount):

[image]

However, both beat your algorithm by quite a lot:

[image]

Comment: If you're going down the itertools route, I think `groupby` would be a little bit clearer than `takewhile`. That is, `list(next(groupby(Counter(integers).most_common(), key=lambda x:x[1]))[1])`

Comment: @GarethRees Not sure if it is any clearer with those nested calls, but it is a nice alternative. I added it to the answer.

Comment: @GarethRees Added some timings and `groupby` seems to be consistently faster than `takewhile` (but not by much). Both are a lot better than the OP's approach, though.

Comment: In real code you'd use variables instead of nested function applications, but I only have this little comment box to type into! The reason why the `groupby` approach is faster is that it avoids a duplicate call to `most_common`.

Answer (score 4):

There are some things that will make this code cleaner and faster. `int_freq = Counter(int_list)` will automatically initialize the counter without you doing work. Also `values = sorted(int_freq.values(), reverse=True)` will be cleaner and faster. Other than that this looks pretty good.